# AngularJS and UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm going mad trying to get UI-Router working they way I want. I'm not trying to do anything complicated but whatever I try I hit the same problem. All I want to do is create the following link structures:

- /Orders
- /Order/AddOrder

/Orders - Display all the orders. This works fine I can refresh the page and it reloads fine.

/Orders/AddOrder - Add a new order. This works if I click a link from the orders page but once I'm there if I refresh the page with F5 or I type the URL directly I get the template for the page load and then another two version of the template nested within each other.

This is my config:

```
angular.module('hecpApp').config([
    '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/orders');

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'HtmlPartials/Home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                breadcrumb: { title: 'Home' },
                unauthenticated: true
            })
            .state('orders', {
                abstract: true,
                template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
            })
                .state('orders.list', {
                    url: '/orders',
                    templateUrl: 'HtmlPartials/Orders.html',
                    controller: 'OrdersCtrl',
                    breadcrumb: { title: 'Orders' },
                    unauthenticated: true
                })
                .state('orders.addorder', {
                    url: '/orders/addorder',
                    templateUrl: 'HtmlPartials/AddOrder.html',
                    controller: 'AddOrderCtrl',
                    breadcrumb: { title: 'Add Order' },
                    unauthenticated: true
                })
            .state('bounce', {
                // Workaround for $state.reload issue see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/76
                // and $state.bounce function declared in app.run
                template: '<h4>Loading...</h4>'
            });
    }
]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I've got the following setup in my web.config:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <!--<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/bundles/.*$" negate="true" />-->
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: You need to either set HTML5 mode to false, or set things up on the server end to route all arguments to the route of your SPA. This isn't really an angular problem, it's a server configuration problem.

Comment: @JMK I've already got some routing setup in my web.config see edit above.